# How well did Cardano understand elementary probabilities, as shown from his writings?

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, probability

I was recently reading a paper on the historical development of probability theory where Cardano is presented as having discovered some elementary laws of probability in the 1550s. But he is described as confusing the multiplication rule for independent events with the multiplication of the odds of these events.
How well did he really understand probability and what is the most likely way that he derived these results?

Comment: What are the title and author of this paper?

Comment: @kimchilover I don't remember sorry.

Comment: Was it a published paper in a journal, or a student effort, or what?

Comment: @kimchilover it was a published paper in a journal.

Comment: Was it David Bellhouse, "Decoding Cardano's Liber de Ludo Aleae" in Historia Mathematica, 2005?

Comment: @kimchilover No.It was this: http://www.columbia.edu/~pg2113/index_files/Gorroochurn-Some%20Laws.pdf  and I misremembered its content since what is written is that cardano multiplied the odds instead of the probabilities.